# Javascript gives InvalidCharacterError

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following line in Javascript that gives an 'InvalidCharacterError', I can't figure out which character is causing the issue, can anyone tell?

`var objResetBtn = document.createElement('<input type="button" value="Reset" class="button" onclick=SetResetRadio("rdUserDefined10"); >');`

Comment: createElement only takes a tagName as an argument, not a HTML string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create HTML elements like that. You might be used to that because you can in jQuery.  You need to do it like this:

```
var el       = document.createElement('input');
el.type      = 'button';
el.className = 'button';
el.value     = 'Reset';
el.onclick   = function() {
    SetResetRadio("rdUserDefined10");
}
```